# Characteristic functions of intervals

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Could you explain to me what characteristic functions of intervals are? I'm reading something about convergence of sequences of functions and it says there that characteristic functions
of intervals are in the set of functions that are the pointwise limits of continuous functions.

Do you think you could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Stone-Weierstrass theorem?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characteristic function on an interval $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is the function given by the rule
$$
\chi_{[a, b]}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c@{,\quad}l} 1 & x \in [a, b] \\ 0 & x \notin [a,b]. \end{array}\right.
$$

It's like a light switch that "turns on" for $x$ in the interval.

One nice use of a characteristic function is to modify a given function $f$ so that it only gives its values on the interval (otherwise $0$).

$$
\left( f \cdot \chi_{[a, b]} \right)(x) = f(x) \cdot \chi_{[a, b]}(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c@{,\quad}l} f(x) & x \in [a, b] \\ 0 & x \notin [a,b]. \end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: so it like ramp function which is  x when x>=0 and zero otherwise.in this case interval is [0,+infinity]

Comment: The characteristic function only gives values $0$ or $1$.

Comment: The characteristic function on $[0, \infty]$ is essentially the Heaviside step function (depending on how you define the value at $0$).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Comment: yes yes i see.just  take one example  .ramp  function we can determine as characteristic function with  binary values

Comment: By ramp function, you mean $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$ and $f(x) = x$ for $x \ge 0$?  Then, $f(x) = x \cdot \chi_{[0, \infty]}$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic function of the set $A$ is the function $\mathbf 1_A$ defined by $\mathbf 1_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $\mathbf 1_A(x)=0$ otherwise. If $A=[a,b]$, then $u_n\to\mathbf 1_A$ pointwise, where $u_n(x)=\exp(-nd(x,A))$. One can adapt this idea to the case when $A$ is an open interval or a semi-open semi-closed interval.